# How to skip_before_action for devise_token_auth sessions#create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-api

I have a Rails 5 app (api only). I am using [devise_token_auth](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth) for authentication. In the app I have several controllers, For all of the controllers I would like to `authenticate_user!`. I would like to avoid repeating the line `before_action :authenticate_user!`, so I placed it in ApplicationController.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::API
  include DeviseTokenAuth::Concerns::SetUserByToken
  before_action :authenticate_user!
end
```

With this approach, `authenticate_user!` is called even during login and register. How can I skip `:authenticate_user!` for login, register and logout? I tried to monkey patch SessionsController to add `skip_before_action` .

```
module DeviseTokenAuth
  class SessionsController
    skip_before_action :authenticate_user!, only: [:create, :destroy, ]
  end
end
```

But controllers are lazy loaded, so I get following error:

```
undefined method `skip_before_action' for DeviseTokenAuth::SessionsController:Class
```

What am I missing? Any other solution? Thank for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Your `SessionsController` class should inherit from `Devise::SessionsController` to make use of the `skip_before_action` class method.

```
module DeviseTokenAuth
  class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
    skip_before_action :authenticate_user!, only: [:create, :destroy]
  end
end
```

Comment: I don't want to create my own SessionsController. I would like to use DeviseTokenAuth::SessionsController.

Comment: I am afraid, I won't be able to utilize existing devise_token_auth routes.

Comment: @Mo3z What do you mean?

Comment: devise_token_auth provides routes for sign_in, sign_out and register. If I create a new controller, wouldn't I have to create new routes?

Answer (score 0):

You can declare this after

```
before_action :authenticate_user! 
  
::DeviseTokenAuth::SessionsController.class_eval do
  skip_before_action :authenticate_user!
end
```